# Conditional Case and LIKE/ILIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why is LIKE/ILIKE not working with the WHEN from the Conditional Case Statement?

```
    SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN rating='NC-17' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS NC_17,
    CASE
        WHEN rating='R' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS R,
        CASE
        WHEN rating ILIKE 'pg' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS PG,
    CASE
        WHEN rating ILIKE 'pg___' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS PG_13,
        CASE
        WHEN rating='G' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS G
FROM film
```

[image: SQL Error]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also what are the data types of the columns?

Comment: What data type is `rating`? The error message seems to indicate an enum.

Comment: Next time please copy your error message to your request (as plain text). At first I didn't see the link and assumed from your explanation that `ILIKE` didn't detect matches, while I see now that you are getting an exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, why not just use boolean columns.  There is no need for the `case` expression.  Second, the error is explicitly saying that conversion will help.  So does this work?

```
SELECT (rating = 'NC-17') AS NC_17,
       (rating = 'R') as R,
       (rating ILIKE 'pg'::text) AS PG,
       (rating ILIKE 'pg___'::text) AS PG_13,
       (rating = 'G') AS G
FROM film
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, thanks for the feedback. I just showed the first part of what I was doing. So, my intention is to do that first and then sum each of these 'Case' conditionals to get one column of sum for each rating. I wouldn't be able to do that with SELECT